# Skaffold on Apple M1 with Docker: How to ensure Rosetta 2 is being used instead of QEMU emulator?

Tags: docker, x86-64, apple-m1, arm64, skaffold

I have an M1 machine (arch arm64) and tI'mrying to build a docker-image with `platform=linux/amd64`.

- When I try to build from the terminal as follwoing: `docker build  --platform linux/amd64 .` it works properly.
- When I try to build through `Skaffold` with `skaffold buil` I get the error further below

```
### Skaffold.yaml, artifact build.
      - image: $IMAGE
        context: .
        custom:
          buildCommand: docker build --platform linux/amd64 .
```

> PS: I have Rosetta2 installed properly and activated through my Docker-desktop.

It seems that `Skaffold` is using `QEMU`  emulator instead of `Rosetta 2`

> #6 97.59 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is
> not installed #6 97.70 Fetched 35.6 MB in 57s (628 kB/s) #6 97.74
> Error while loading /usr/sbin/dpkg-split: No such file or directory #6
> 97.75 Error while loading /usr/sbin/dpkg-deb: No such file or directory #6 97.75 dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18_amd64.deb
> (--unpack): #6 97.75  dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error
> exit status 1 #6 97.75 Error while loading /usr/sbin/dpkg-split: No
> such file or directory #6 97.75 Error while loading
> /usr/sbin/dpkg-deb: No such file or directory #6 97.75 dpkg: error
> processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.7_amd64.deb
> (--unpack): #6 97.75  dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error
> exit status 1 #6 97.76 Error while loading /usr/sbin/dpkg-split: No
> such file or directory #6 97.76 Error while loading
> /usr/sbin/dpkg-deb: No such file or directory #6 97.76 dpkg: error
> processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libexpat1_2.2.9-1ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb
> (--unpack): #6 97.76  dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error
> exit status 1 #6 97.76 Error while loading /usr/sbin/dpkg-split: No
> such file or directory #6 97.77 Error while loading
> /usr/sbin/dpkg-deb: No such file or directory #6 97.77 dpkg: error
> processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.7_amd64.deb
> (--unpack): #6 97.77  dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error
> exit status 1 #6 97.78 Errors were encountered while processing: #6
> 97.78  /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18_amd64.deb #6 97.78  /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.7_amd64.deb
> #6 97.78  /var/cache/apt/archives/libexpat1_2.2.9-1ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb #6 97.78  /var/cache/apt/archives/python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.7_amd64.deb
> #6 97.86 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) #6 ERROR: executor failed running [/dev/.buildkit_qemu_emulator /bin/sh
> -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&     apt-get update &&     add-apt-repository -y
> ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr5 &&     add-apt-repository -y
> ppa:reviczky/xxhash &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y
> libgl1      tesseract-ocr      poppler-utils     fonts-liberation
> libtiff5-dev     libjpeg-turbo8-dev     libopenjp2-7-dev
> zlib1g-dev     libfreetype6-dev     liblcms2-dev     libwebp-dev
> tcl8.6-dev     tk8.6-dev     python3-tk     libharfbuzz-dev
> libfribidi-dev libxcb1-dev     libspatialindex-dev      python3-dev
> wget     make     curl     python3.8-venv      git     build-essential
> python-is-python3     xxhash &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit
> code: 100 ------  > [the_img  2/37] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get
> install -y software-properties-common &&     apt-get update &&
>
> add-apt-repository -y ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr5 &&
>
> add-apt-repository -y ppa:reviczky/xxhash &&     apt-get update &&
>
> apt-get install -y      libgl1      tesseract-ocr      poppler-utils
>
> fonts-liberation     libtiff5-dev     libjpeg-turbo8-dev
>
> libopenjp2-7-dev     zlib1g-dev     libfreetype6-dev     liblcms2-dev
> libwebp-dev     tcl8.6-dev     tk8.6-dev     python3-tk
>
> libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev libxcb1-dev     libspatialindex-dev
>
> python3-dev     wget     make     curl     python3.8-venv      git
>
> build-essential     python-is-python3     xxhash &&     rm -rf
> /var/lib/apt/lists/*: #6 97.76 Error while loading
> /usr/sbin/dpkg-split: No such file or directory #6 97.77 Error while
> loading /usr/sbin/dpkg-deb: No such file or directory #6 97.77 dpkg:
> error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.7_amd64.deb
> (--unpack): #6 97.77  dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error
> exit status 1 #6 97.78 Errors were encountered while processing: #6
> 97.78  /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18_amd64.deb #6 97.78  /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.7_amd64.deb
> #6 97.78  /var/cache/apt/archives/libexpat1_2.2.9-1ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb #6 97.78  /var/cache/apt/archives/python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.7_amd64.deb
> #6 97.86 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) ------ ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/dev/.buildkit_qemu_emulator /bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get
> install -y software-properties-common &&     apt-get update &&
> add-apt-repository -y ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr5 &&
> add-apt-repository -y ppa:reviczky/xxhash &&     apt-get update &&
> apt-get install -y      libgl1      tesseract-ocr      poppler-utils
> fonts-liberation     libtiff5-dev     libjpeg-turbo8-dev
> libopenjp2-7-dev     zlib1g-dev     libfreetype6-dev     liblcms2-dev
> libwebp-dev     tcl8.6-dev     tk8.6-dev     python3-tk
> libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev libxcb1-dev     libspatialindex-dev
> python3-dev     wget     make     curl     python3.8-venv      git
> build-essential     python-is-python3     xxhash &&     rm -rf
> /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100 Cleaning up... Error: uninstall:
> Release not loaded: keycloak: release: not found Error: uninstall:
> Release not loaded: proxy: release: not found Error: uninstall:
> Release not loaded: minio: release: not found Error: uninstall:
> Release not loaded: mock-model-registry: release: not found

- I have tried to run `arch -x86_64 skaffold build`.
- I installed Rosetta 2 and activated it.

---

- It seems that Skaffold is using QEMU  emulator instead of Rosetta 2
- I want to make sure `Skaffold` is using Rosetta 2

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to fix the problem with these three steps:

1. Updated Skaffold to its latest version `brew update skaffold`
2. Updated Rosetta `softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`
3. Downgraded `docker-desktop` from its latest (4.19.0) to 4.17.0